# SQL : ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE Store
(
    Store_Name VARCHAR2(20) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    Year_Opened DATE,
    Manager VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL
);
    
CREATE TABLE Store1
(
    Store VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL
        REFERENCES Store(Store_Name),
    Department VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( Store, Department )
);
    
CREATE TABLE Inventory
(
    Inventory_No VARCHAR2(8) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    Store VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL
        REFERENCES Store1(Store),
    Department VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL
        REFERENCES Store1(Department)
);
```

Just wondering why I keep getting this same error over and over. I am referencing the right table and the column I am referencing is a primary key so I'm not sure why I am getting an error. Any help will be gratefully appreciated Thank you.

Full error:

> ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
> 02270. 00000 -  "no matching unique or primary key for this column-list"
>
> *Cause: A REFERENCES clause in a CREATE/ALTER TABLE statement gives a column-list for which there is no matching unique or primary key constraint in the referenced table.
>
> *Action: Find the correct column names using the ALL_CONS_COLUMNS catalog view

Answer (score 3):

> I am referencing the right table and the column I am referencing is a primary key

Not really.

From table `inventory`, you're referencing `Store1 (Store)`, but `store1` table's primary key is defined as`PRIMARY KEY ( Store, Department )`.

You can't reference *part* of the primary key.

It would work if you modified the foreign key constraint as follows:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE Store(
  2      Store_Name VARCHAR2(20) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  3      Year_Opened DATE,
  4      Manager VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL
  5  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE Store1(
  2      Store VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL
  3          REFERENCES Store(Store_Name),
  4      Department VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
  5      PRIMARY KEY ( Store, Department )
  6      );

Table created.

SQL>  CREATE TABLE Inventory(
  2      Inventory_No VARCHAR2(8) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  3      Store VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
  4      Department VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
  5      --
  6      constraint fk_inv_sto foreign key (store, department)
  7        references store1 (store, department)
  8  );

Table created.

SQL>
```